# ng-model doesn't update value when using JQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, datepicker

So I have two textboxes for the user to select a date and I am using JqQuery's datepicker UI to display a small calendar popup when the textbox is clicked. Now the problem is that when I click on the textbox, the calendar pops up, I select a date and then the textbox gets filled with that date and my scope variable in javascript also gets updated. However, in my HTML, the value of "From" date box doesn't get printed until I click on "To" date box. Below is my code:

*home.html*

```
<form name="myForm">
From Date:
<input type="text" id="dateFrom" ng-model="data.dateFromChosen" />
To Date:
<input type="text" id="dateTo" ng-model="data.dateToChosen" />
</form>

<p>You chose: {{ data.dateFromChosen }} and {{ data.dateToChosen }}</p>
```

*script.js*

```
$scope.data = {};
$("#dateFrom").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $scope.data.dateFromChosen = $("#dateFrom").datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy'}).val();
        alert("You chose " + $scope.data.dateFromChosen);
    }
});
$("#dateTo").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $scope.data.dateToChosen = $("#dateTo").datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy'}).val();
        alert("You chose " + $scope.data.dateToChosen);
    }
});
```

So this is what happens: I click on `from date` box and select a date. Then I get the popup saying that `You chose 06/01/2016` which means the `$scope.data.dateFromChosen = 06/01/2016`. But it doesn't get displayed in my HTML. Then when I click on `to date` box, the value of `dateFromChosen` gets printed on HTML. Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding $scope.$apply() to force angular to rerun digest cycle.

```
$scope.data = {};
$("#dateFrom").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $scope.data.dateFromChosen = $("#dateFrom").datepicker({dateFormat:     'mm/dd/yyyy'}).val();
        $scope.$apply();
        alert("You chose " + $scope.data.dateFromChosen);
    }
});
$("#dateTo").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $scope.data.dateToChosen = $("#dateTo").datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy'}).val();
        $scope.$apply();
        alert("You chose " + $scope.data.dateToChosen);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. The calendar popup didn't close automatically when i would click on a date, I had to click outside the box somewhere but still same issue persists.

Comment: Nothing more comes to my mind at the moment :/ You should avoid mixing jQuery and Angular code because it is very problematic. Maybe try [this repo](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date)